How to not check for pre-existing caches with mapproxy-seed?
The Swedish Geological Survey provides this WMS endpoint: https://resource.sgu.se/service/wms/130/jorddjupsmodell. I would like to create WMTS tiles from the SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL layer.
Visualisation in QGIS:

To create the WMTS tiles, I use MapProxy's Seeding functionality: mapproxy-seed. During seeding, a list of tiles are generated and cached.
The command I use to achieve this:
mapproxy-seed --proxy-conf=mapproxy.yaml --seed-conf=seed.yaml --concurrency 10

The referenced mapproxy.yaml file, which details the source & the cache used:
services:
  demo:
  wmts:

layers:
  - name: jorddjup
    title: jorddjup
    sources: [jorddjup_cache]

caches:
  jorddjup_cache:
    grids: [webmercator]
    sources: [jorddjup_wms]
    cache:
      type: s3
      bucket_name: an-s3-bucket

sources:
  jorddjup_wms:
    type: wms
    req:
      url: https://maps3.sgu.se/geoserver/misc/ows?
      layers: SE.GOV.SGU.MISC.JORDDJUPSMODELL.RASTER_INTERVALL

grids:
    webmercator:
        base: GLOBAL_WEBMERCATOR

The other file referenced in the command is seed.yaml, this configures the seeding itself:
coverages:
  swedenbbox:
    bbox: [10.57, 55.12, 24.2, 69.07]
    srs: 'EPSG:4326'

seeds:
  myseed1:
    caches: [jorddjup_cache]
    coverages: [swedenbbox]
    refresh_before:
      minutes: 0
    levels:
      to: 12

Start of the output:
========== Seeding tasks ==========
Start seeding process (1 task)
  myseed1:
    Seeding cache 'jorddjup_cache' with grid 'webmercator' in EPSG:3857
    Limited to coverage in: 10.57000, 55.12000, 24.20000, 69.07000 (EPSG:4326)
    Levels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
    Overwriting: tiles older than 2024-04-21 21:00:04
[21:00:04]  0   0.00% 1176647.01768, 7385190.58366, 2693931.67720, 10772565.24871 (0 tiles)
[21:00:07]  9   6.25% 1176647.01768, 10018754.17139, 1252344.27142, 10644926.30711 (208 tiles)
[21:00:11] 11   7.81% 1176647.01768, 10331840.23925, 1252344.27142, 10488383.27318 (384 tiles)

I would like to cache all tiles, without even checking whether a previous cache exist or not. Currently, line 7 of the output:
Overwriting: tiles older than 2024-04-21 21:00:04
suggests that the creation time of existing tiles are checked. Based on Line 237 of mapproxy/mapproxy/seed/util.py, Line 7 could have been:
Overwriting: all tiles.
This is what I am aiming for. I tried removing the lines:
refresh_before:
  minutes: 0

from seed.yaml, but then line 7 of the output is Overwriting: no tiles. The opposite of what I want.
How to not check for pre-existing caches with mapproxy-seed?

Check disable_storage: https://mapproxy.github.io/mapproxy/latest/configuration.html#disable-storage.
